# Looping through properties conditionally using reflection

Tags: c#

I am using a web service to return me a `JsonAddressModel` in return for a uprn `string` within my application in various places.

I have a requirement to print a customers address as a concatenated `string` on a confirmation page of my form.

I initially wrote this method, which is designed to comma separate each property and omit any which are null, which works well however is admittedly quite repetitive.

**Original Method**

```
public static string ConcatAddress(JsonAddressModel jsonAddressModel)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    if (jsonAddressModel.saon.Replace(" ", "") != "" && jsonAddressModel != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.saon + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.paon != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.paon + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.thorofare != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.thorofare + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.dthorofare != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.dthorofare + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.posttown != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.posttown + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.county != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.county + ", ");

    if (jsonAddressModel.postcode != null)
        builder.Append(jsonAddressModel.postcode);

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

After testing this, I sought to refactor in a more elegant manner, and decided I would try and use reflection to work out the properties of `JsonAddressModel` and append each one in turn using a `foreach` loop.

**New Method**

```
public static string ConcatAddress(JsonAddressModel jsonAddressModel)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in jsonAddressModel.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop != null)
        {    
            builder.Append(prop.GetValue(jsonAddressModel, null) + ",");
        }
    }                
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

**Problem**

Whilst the new method is now appending each of the correct properties that I want displayed such as the saon/paon, thorofare etc. It is also appending the eastings, northings, uprn as well as stuff like `System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject` which are obviously things I do not wish to include in my concatenated address string.

**Question**

Is there anyway of stipulating exactly which properties I allow to be appended here?

I don't think `BindingFlags` will work in my instance because as mentioned previously I am receiving this model from a web service and both the properties I want, and don't want, respectively are `Private`.

I've considered creating an Array however the only name related field I can see is the `SetMethod` which will be something like `SetMethod = {Void set_saon(System.String)}` but for each property, and I'm not fully sure how to get a handle on this.

Comment: You could create your own attribute and decorate each of the properties with it and check that a given property has this attribute before getting it's value.

Comment: @ric Could you provide an example of this please?

Comment: Do you have any control over the `JsonAddressModel`?

Comment: Currently, no. However I suppose I could create a ViewModel and have AutoMapper map it over each time.

Comment: How do you want to control what properties get appended? It could be as simple as passing in a list of strings for example.

Comment: If you could convert it to a view model with only properties that you need then that would solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that there's a way to do what you're asking via reflection, but you don't really provide any information on what the difference is between the items you want to include and those you don't.

However, in this case, you can certainly eliminate the repetition in your code while keeping the important parts (i.e. the part that determines which items to include in the output), and as a bonus it'll be more efficient than using reflection.

```
    public static string ConcatAddress(JsonAddressModel jsonAddressModel)
    {
        var nonEmptyProperties = new [] {
            jsonAddressModel.saon,
            jsonAddressModel.paon,
            jsonAddressModel.thorofare,
            jsonAddressModel.dthorofare,
            jsonAddressModel.posttown,
            jsonAddressModel.county,
            jsonAddressModel.postcode,
        }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
        return string.Join(", ", nonEmptyProperties);
    }
```

Comment: The properties I want are the ones in the first method, theres around 4 extras such as the ones I mentioned (eastings, northings, uprn & the ExtensionDataObject) which I don't want.

Comment: This is better than reflection, although I would skip the variable and just `return`.

Comment: How does this know not to put a trailing comma after the postcode?

Comment: @selectDistinct: The extra comma I have after the postcode is in C# syntax, and it's not necessary, but it doesn't change the compiled code because the compiler recognizes there's nothing after it, so it's just ignored. `string.Join()` is responsible for adding the ", " between each item in the array that's passed in to it, and it knows not to add anything after the last item.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method which is a bit more generic and you can specify the parameters in the function call:

```
public string ConcatProperties<T>(T input, params Func<T, string>[] propertyDelegates)
{
    return string.Join(
        ",", 
        propertyDelegates
            .Select(p => p(input))
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var concatenatedString = ConcatProperties(thingy,
    x => x.Foo,
    x => x.Bar,
    x => x.Wobble);
```

Note: This only works with string properties, for others you need to convert properties to strings (e.g. `x => x.Wibble.ToString()`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's quite easy with Linq:

Instead of using directly

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in jsonAddressModel.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   // ...
}
```

you can use

```
var desiredProperties = new List<string>
{
    "saon",
    "paon"
};
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> pis = jsonAddressModel.GetType().GetProperties();
var filteredPropertyInfos = pis.Where(pi => desiredProperties.Contains(pi.Name));

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in filteredPropertyInfos)
{
   // ...
}
```